# sql query to display records ordered by date in descending order, i have an error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

This gives me an error-

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value.

This doesn't work and had tried this too, but this orders by date not month

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Member where Email LIKE '" + id.ToString() + "%' ORDER BY YEAR(RegisterDT) DESC,MONTH (RegisterDT) DESC, DAY(RegisterDT) DESC", con);


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Member where Email LIKE '" + id.ToString() + "%' ORDER BY(RegisterDT) DESC", con)
```

Comment: Is `RegisterDT` column a date? If so, post examples of values,

Answer (score 3):

When posting a question, it is a good idea to give the table format, the database you are using, and sample data.  In this case, I speculate that you are using SQL Server, because you are using the DAY() and MONTH() functions.

These functions take dates as arugments, not strings.  You should not depend on implicit conversion in SQL.  Let me repeat that.  You should always explicitly convert between data types, to prevent errors like the ones you see.

The problem that you have is that your date format is not in the default format for the system.  For instance, you may have a date like 10/03/2012.  Is this Oct 3rd, as Americans would believe?  Or is this March 10th, as Europeans would?  Then consider 10/20/2012.  It is out of range for Europeans.

So, you have two options:

(1) Do an explicit conversion, using the CONVERT() function.

(2) Extract the month and day using string functions.  In the above case, this might be substring(, 1, 2) for one and substring(, 4, 2) for the other.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that RegisterDT is a char column and you have an invalid date in there for your current date settings (DMY | MDY). Dates should be stored as dates, not strings. This should resolve your problem.

As a first side point, if RegisterDT is a date column, why do you have to break it down by year, month day? Why can't you just `ORDER BY RegisterDT DESC`?

As a final side point [BEWARE SQL INJECTION](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should be using paramerised queries like so:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Member WHERE Email LIKE @ID + '%' ORDER BY RegisterDT DESC", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = id.ToString();
```

This not only elimates SQL injection, it also makes code more readable by separating SQL from values, and stops data loss through string conversion.